# Characteristics of the IBM quantum computer

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, error-correction, ibm-quantum-devices

On the IBM Quantum Composer website, there are characteristics of qubit computers. For example, ibmq_16_melbourne.
But there is no description anywhere of what:

`T1(us)`,
`T2(us)`,
`Frequency (GHz)`,
`Readout assignment error`,
`Prob meas0 prep1`,
`Prob meas1 prep0`,
`Readout length (ns)`,
`ID error`,
`√x (sx) error`,
`Single-qubit Pauli-X error`,
`CNOT error`,
`Gate time (ns)` means.

Could you write down what they mean?

And why isn't there, for example, a `Pauli-Z error`, even though there is a `Pauli-X error`?

[image: Characteristics of the IBM quantum computer]

Comment: To close voters: It has a fabulous answer, so please stop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick and dirty list:

- **$T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$** -  colloquially known as *decoherence times*, but slightly more precisely also as the (qubit) *relaxation* time ($T_{1}$) and the (qubit) *dephasing* time ($T_{2}$).
- $T_{1}$ is a measure of how quickly a qubit in the excited ($|1\rangle$) state spontaneously relaxes to the ground ($|0\rangle$) state.
- $T_{2}$ is slightly more tricky: it is a measure of how fast a *coherent* superposition (one with a well-defined relative phase between the $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$) loses this 'well-defined-ness'. Essentially, it's what makes a qubit a *quantum* phenomenon; a (completely) dephased qubit is just a probabilistic classical bit.
- **Frequency** - the qubits from IBM are [superconducting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_quantum_computing) qubits. Interactions with these qubits are performed via microwave resonators; to address each different qubit separately each' qubits resonator has a different frequency. As @Lena has [pointed out](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17063/8141), the frequency is actually defined as the energy difference between the $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states.
- **Readout assignment error** - measure of how well the measurement performs - as [luciano](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17059/8141) mentions in his answer, the probability of a measurement returning the wrong value.
- **Prob meas0 prep1** - The probability that a measurement returns $0$ immediately after preparing the $|1\rangle$ state. A combination of faulty preparation and faulty measurements; these are also often referred to as SPAM (*state-preparation-and-measurement*) errors.
- **Prob meas1 prep0** - like the previous one
- **Readout length (ns)** - time it takes to perform a measurement in (ns). One of the main limiting factors of current quantum hardware; as these times are often considerably longer than the $T_{2}$, which makes intermediate measurements (i.e. measurements that are not at the end of a circuit) practically unfeasible.
- **ID error** - measure of the error induced by having the qubit idle (for a typical gate time). The measure used is, I believe, that 'returned' by [randomized benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_benchmarking), which closely resembles the process fidelity.
- **$\sqrt{X}$ error** - measure of error induced by applying the gate in question. Average over all different qubits.
- **Single-qubit Pauli X error** - likewise
- **CNOT error** - error of the only two-qubit gate natively implementable on the IBM devices. Average over all possible CNOT gates
- **Gate time (ns)** - [Lena to the rescue again](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17063/8141) - this is related to the time it takes to perform a CNOT, the two-qubit gate.

> And why isn't there, for example, a Pauli-Z error, even though there is a Pauli-X error?

The reason there is no error shown for the Pauli Z is because there is (virtually) none. This is because the IBM machines don't really implement $Z$ rotations - they keep track of the $Z$ rotations through software, and update the $X$ (and $Y$) gates accordingly. Effectively, they rotate the $X$ and $Y$ axes of the Bloch sphere along the $Z$ axis - the 'Pauli X' gate is thus actually any rotation along an axis in the $X-Y$ plane of the Bloch sphere. By changing the phase of the induced wave on the resonator, one can pick the angle the axis makes with a predetermined reference point, and thus implement both $X$ and $Y$ gates.

You might also find [this page on system properties](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/systems/properties) and [this qiskit notebook on calibration](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html) useful.

Comment: Regarding square root X error what's the meaning of the sentence "Average over all different qubits." Does this mean that the error is divided by the number of qubits in the ibmq system ? or you mean they test the system many times and calculate the average error for each qubit ? or something else ? Please clarify the meaning for me.

Answer (score 7):

Just adding some stuff to the already good answer :

- The gate time actually is related to the connexion between qubits, so is related to the CNOT, not the single-qubit gates.
- The frequency is defined as the difference in energy between the ground and excited states, i.e. the |0⟩ and |1⟩ states, respectively.
- for more info about how to measure all this (T1, T2, frequency), you could check [this tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html) showing all this.
- about the errors of Z/X, the basis gates of all the different available backends are the cx, x, sx, and rz. So you won't have any error rate for Z but you will have for X because of this.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind if I merge this with my current answer?